# The submitted data was invalid

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have this error when I refresh page content form then persistent object.

[image]

code handler: content function post when I create form with handle :

```
  public function post(array $parameters, bool $submitted = false, array $options = [])
        {

            $recruiter = $this->formHandler->handle(
                $this->factory->create(),
                $parameters,
                Request::METHOD_POST,
                $submitted,
                $options
            );
            if ($recruiter instanceof Recruiter) {

            $this->repository->save($recruiter);

            return $recruiter;
        }
    }
```

code controller: use function post for handler and I use try and catch:

```
/**
         * @Template()
         * @Route("/register", name="register_recruiter")
         *
         * @param Request $request
         *
         * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
         */
        public function registerAction(Request $request)
        {
                  try {


                $quiz = $this->getHandler()->post($request->request->all());



                return $this->redirectToRoute('recruiter_quizs_index');

            } 
            catch (InvalidFormException $e) {
                return [
                    'form' => $e->getForm()->createView(),
                    'edit' => false,
                ];
            }
```

code twig content form :

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

function handle for create form:

```
public function handle($object, array $parameters, string $method, bool $submited = false, array $options = [])
        {
            $options = array_replace_recursive([
                'method' => $method,
                'csrf_protection' => false,
            ], $options);
            $form = $this->formFactory->create(get_class($this->formType), $object, $options);
            if (!$submited) {

                throw new InvalidFormException($form);
            }
            $form->submit($parameters, 'PATCH' !== $method);
            if (!$form->isValid()) {
                throw new InvalidFormException($form);
            }

            return $form->getData();
        }
```

Comment: help me pease ....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do not provide a value for the 2nd parameter `$submitted`, which should probably be `true` if the method is POST, PUT or PATCH.

The easy way to fix this is checking for the method in the action and provide the boolean parameter

```
    /**
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/register", name="register_recruiter")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $submitted = ($request->isMethod('PATCH') || $request->isMethod('POST') || $request->isMethod('PUT'));
            $quiz = $this->getHandler()->post($request->request->all(), $submitted);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('recruiter_quizs_index');
        } 
        catch (InvalidFormException $e) {
            return [
                'form' => $e->getForm()->createView(),
                'edit' => false,
            ];
        }
```

Although I think this is a really bad solution. You should create an action for each HTTP method. Show the form with GET, submit it with POST/PUT/PATCH. Put the submit route before the GET route, so it will match first:

```
    /**
     * submit the recruiter form (on PATH, POST, PUT)
     *
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/register", name="register_recruiter_submit", methods={"PATCH","POST","PUT"})
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function registerSubmitAction(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $quiz = $this->getHandler()->post($request->request->all(), true);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('recruiter_quizs_index');
        } 
        catch (InvalidFormException $e) {
            return [
                'form' => $e->getForm()->createView(),
                'edit' => false,
            ];
        }
    }

    /**
     * show the recruiter form (route will match if method is not PATCH/PUT/POST
     *
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/register", name="register_recruiter_form")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function registerFormAction(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'form' => $this->formHandler->createView(),
            'edit' => false,
        ];
    }
```